# Is there a notion analogous to “the inductive conception of set” in modal logic?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, modal-logic, set-theory

In many introductory treatments of modal logic, one defines a Kripke model with respect to some domain D. In variable domain semantics, each world in the Kripke model is assigned a different subset of a global domain as its domain. Philosophically, variable domain semantics is nice because it allows one to reason about potential but non-actual objects. But, like fixed domain semantics, it still seems to require us to think of the possible worlds we are considering as forming a single set. This seems undesirable for reasons that are analogous to the undesirability of a universal set in set theory. Intuitively, it seems we can always ask with respect to any set of possibilities whether it is possible that those possibilities could have been different. Modality seems to be what Michael Dummett called an “indefinitely extensible concept”. This raises three questions in my mind to which I would be grateful to receive answers:

(1) Have people worked on an iteratively generated universe of possible worlds?

(2) If so, what implications does this have for the notion of “metaphysical possibility” (i.e, the idea that there is a determinate, maximally comprehensive domain of discourse for alethic modality).

(3) I know some mathematicians have given modal analyses of set theory, trying to capture the “indefinite extensibility” of set theory with modal notions. Does the apparent indefinite extensibility of modal notions raise any issues for these kinds of projects?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the analogy between the universal set and the set of all possible worlds? The problem with the universal set (combined with unrestricted comprehension) is that it creates a contradiction via Russel's Paradox. Are you claiming that your question of whether the possibilities could have been different raises such a contradiction? How so? If not, what analogy are you referring to?

Comment: @DavidGudeman It seems like we can sensibly discuss different ways the metaphysical facts might have been. If metaphysical possibility is really maximally inclusive, and it's possible that the metaphysical facts could have been different, then it seems like we might be vulnerable to some diagonal argument. Let M be a Kripke model representing the metaphysically possible worlds. It can't be the case that M is a member of W, where M =  <W, R, V>. But if the metaphysical possibilities could have been different, then M is one possiblity among many, and therfore should be in W.